# Confirm that ( x + d/dx ) exp( -x^2 / 2 ) = 0

Tags: matlab, math, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I have written a small code that is supposed to verify that `( x +  d/dx ) exp(-x^2 / 2 ) = 0`. The idea is to use a Fourier series `exp( 2 * pi j n x / L )` with sufficiently large `L` to represent the Gaussian and perform the operation there.

The algorithm in Matlab works as follows:

```matlab
function[] = verify

    epsilon = 0.05; % step-size numerical integration

    N = 40; % number of Fourier coefficients

    L = 30; % window length numerical integration Fourier basis

    X = -L / 2:epsilon:L / 2; % grid

    xFourier = zeros(2 * N + 1); %Allocate space for Fourier coefficients of f(x)=x

    inix = zeros(2 * N + 1); % Allocate space for Fourier coefficients of f(x)=exp(-x^2/2)

    % Compute Fourier coefficients of f(x)=x
    for i1=-N:N
        A = X.*exp(-2 * pi * 1i * i1. * X / L ) / sqrt( L );
        xFourier(i1 + ( N + 1 ) ) = trapz( X, A ); 
    end

    % Compute Fourier coefficients of f(x)=exp(-x^2/2)
    for i1 = -N : N
        A = 1 / sqrt(L) * exp(-X.^2 / 2 ). * exp(-2 * pi * 1i * i1. * X / L );
        inix( i1 + N + 1 ) = trapz( X, A ); % These are the Fourier coefficients of the |x|^2*Gaussian part
    end
    TO = Hamilton( N, xFourier, L );
    norm( TO * inix' )
end
```

So the heart of the above algorithm is the function Hamilton that I am calling, it contains the matrix representation of the operator `x  d/dx`, which is why `norm( TO * inix' )` should return something close to zero, but it does not(?) and the function Hamilton is as follows

```matlab
function [ Hamilton ] = Hamilton( N, xFourier, L)
    Hamilton = zeros( ( 2 * N + 1 ),( 2 * N + 1 ) );
    for i1 = -N : N
        for i2 = -N : N
            if i1 == i2
                Hamilton( 
                    (i1 + ( N + 1 ) ), ( i2 + ( N + 1 ) ) 
                ) = Hamilton(  
                    ( i1 + ( N + 1)),( i2 + ( N + 1 ) ) 
                ) + 1i * 2 * pi / L * i1;
            end
            if abs( i2 - i1 ) <= N 
                Hamilton( 
                    ( i1 + ( N + 1 ) ), ( i2 + ( N + 1 ) ) 
                ) = Hamilton(
                    (i1 + ( N + 1 ) ), ( i2 + ( N + 1 ) ) 
                ) + xFourier( i1 - i2  + ( N + 1 ) );
            end             
        end
    end
end
```

Does anybody see a mistake?

Comment: There is no LaTex formatting on this site, please [edit] your question to improve the syntax (and improve readability). Also please include more context around your expected output - "should be close to zero" is something you've stated without support here, and it's not clear whether that is wrong or whether something in the code is wrong, and without providing the maths you're trying to implement it's very hard for us to guess which is the case

Comment: Why do you have a variable with the same name as the function? And please choose a consistent indentation and spacing for your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not into Matlab , I somewhat miss a few terms in the code, like the factor `2 pi j k` for the derivative. So here I put a Python version of what I think it should look like (sorry for the Python, but I guess it translates to Matlab quite easily):

```py
import numpy as np

## non-normalized gaussian with sigma=1
def gauss( x ):
    return np.exp( -x**2 / 2 )

## interval on which the gaussian is evaluated
L = 10
## number of sampling points
N = 21
## sample rate
dl = L / N
## highest frequency detectable
kmax= 1 / ( 2 * dl )

## array of x values
xl = np.linspace( -L/2, L/2, N )
## array of k values
kl = np.linspace( -kmax, kmax, N )

## matrix of exponents
## the Fourier transform is defined via sum f * exp( -2 pi j k x)
## i.e. the 2 pi is in the exponent
## normalization is sqrt(N) where n is the number of sampling points
## this definition makes it forward-backward symmetric
## "outer" also exists in Matlab and basically does the same
exponent = np.outer( -1j * 2 * np.pi * kl, xl ) 
## linear operator for the standard Fourier transformation
A = np.exp( exponent ) / np.sqrt( N )

## nth derivative is given via partial integration as  ( 2 pi j k)^n f(k)
## every row needs to be multiplied by the according k
B = np.array( [ 1j * 2 * np.pi * kk * An for kk, An in zip( kl, A ) ] )

## for the part with the linear term, every column needs to be multiplied
## by the according x or--as here---every row is multiplied element 
## wise with the x-vector
C = np.array( [ xl * An for An in  A ] )

## thats the according linear operator
D = B + C

## the gaussian
yl = gauss( xl )

## the transformation with the linear operator
print(  np.dot( D, yl ).round( decimals=9 ) ) 
## ...results in a zero-vector, as expected
```

provides:

```py
[ 0.+4.61e-07j  0.-3.75e-07j  0.+1.20e-08j  0.+3.09e-07j -0.-5.53e-07j
  0.+6.95e-07j -0.-7.28e-07j  0.+6.54e-07j -0.-4.91e-07j -0.+2.62e-07j
 -0.+0.00e+00j -0.-2.62e-07j -0.+4.91e-07j -0.-6.54e-07j  0.+7.28e-07j
 -0.-6.95e-07j  0.+5.53e-07j -0.-3.09e-07j  0.-1.20e-08j  0.+3.75e-07j
  0.-4.61e-07j]
```

This is basically zero.

Comment: Thank you, I have a short question: Question: I would like to understand: If I consider np.dot( B, yl ) for example. Is this now an output on the Fourier side or on the function side? In other words, since B models differentiation with respect to x, how can I use np.dot( B, yl ) to plot the differentiated function at sampling points x for example?

Comment: Hi, `zl = np.dot( B, yl )` is the Fourier transform of the derivative. Technically, you get the derivative in real space by applying the inverse transform to `zl`. This is probably not the best way for a numerical derivative, though. For details, I'd say this is a new question.

Comment: thank you, here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66328679/efficiently-compute-inverse-fourier-transform