# Efficiently compute inverse Fourier transform

Tags: python, math, fft, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

The following code was suggested in the very nice answer to this question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66203905/confirm-that-x-d-dx-exp-x2-2-0)

My question about it is: If I was just to compute the derivative in Fourier space as done in this code by evaluating np.dot( B, yl ). How would I be able to recover the actual derivative in real space by applying an inverse Fourier transform?

```
import numpy as np

## non-normalized gaussian with sigma=1
def gauss( x ):
    return np.exp( -x**2 / 2 )

## interval on which the gaussian is evaluated
L = 10
## number of sampling points
N = 21
## sample rate
dl = L / N
## highest frequency detectable
kmax= 1 / ( 2 * dl )

## array of x values
xl = np.linspace( -L/2, L/2, N )
## array of k values
kl = np.linspace( -kmax, kmax, N )

## matrix of exponents
## the Fourier transform is defined via sum f * exp( -2 pi j k x)
## i.e. the 2 pi is in the exponent
## normalization is sqrt(N) where n is the number of sampling points
## this definition makes it forward-backward symmetric
## "outer" also exists in Matlab and basically does the same
exponent = np.outer( -1j * 2 * np.pi * kl, xl ) 
## linear operator for the standard Fourier transformation
A = np.exp( exponent ) / np.sqrt( N )

## nth derivative is given via partial integration as  ( 2 pi j k)^n f(k)
## every row needs to be multiplied by the according k
B = np.array( [ 1j * 2 * np.pi * kk * An for kk, An in zip( kl, A ) ] )

## for the part with the linear term, every column needs to be multiplied
## by the according x or--as here---every row is multiplied element 
## wise with the x-vector
C = np.array( [ xl * An for An in  A ] )

## thats the according linear operator
D = B + C

## the gaussian
yl = gauss( xl )

## the transformation with the linear operator
print(  np.dot( D, yl ).round( decimals=9 ) ) 
## ...results in a zero-vector, as expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here one only needs to define the linear operator for the inverse transformation.
Following the structure from the posted code it would be

```py
expinv = np.outer( 1j * 2 * np.pi * xl, kl ) 
AInv = np.exp( expinv ) / np.sqrt( N )
```

The Fourier transform of the derivative was

```py
dfF = np.dot( B, yl )
```

such that the derivative in real space would be

```py
dfR = np.dot( AInv, dfF )
```

Eventually, this means that the "derivative"-operator is

```py
np.dot( AInv, B )
```

which is for small `N` ( except for the edges ) a tridiagonal matrix with entries `(-1,0,1)`, i.e. a classical symmetric numerical derivative.
Increasing `N` it first changes to `1,-2,0,2,1` i.e. a higher order approximation of the derivative.

Eventually, one gets an alternating weighted derivative of type `(..., d,-c, b,-a,0,a,-b, c,-d, ...)`

Comment: but then I do not understand, why AInv, is not the inverse matrix associated with A?

Comment: Well, it somewhat is and with increasing `N` the difference is less important. Actually `np.dot( AInv, A)` is the identity matrix except for one additional entry in the first and last row. This probably has to do with the fact that a finite Fourier transform virtually becomes periodic. So technically, and if the number of points is high enough, there is no real difference between calculating the inverse of `A` and constructing it the way I did. From the Fourier point of view the latter is conceptually somewhat better and I suppose that it is faster, from a computational effort point of view.